# Spring-boot: If a method in a Service is @Transactional, and that method calls other methods, are they also transactional?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Lets say I have this method in my @Service that is Transactional. If I call another method in that method, are the database actions in the other method also Transactional as part of the same transaction?

```
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> saveListOfValidationSteps(List<ValidationStep> steps, String controlId, String aNumber){

 deleteOldSteps();
 //calls to repo to add new columns

}

private void deleteOldSteps(){
/calls to repo to delete old columns
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

`@Transactional` under that hood adds a special "around" interceptor that inits the transaction before entering the method and commits / rollbacks when the method finishes.

As long as the method calls other methods in the same thread they all will be a part of transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, code in `deleteOldSteps`() will join the current transaction(started by `saveListOfValidationSteps`).
If you are using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory`, then spring will manage transactions on it's own and will attach `entityManager` instance to `ThreadLocal`, so when code inside `deleteOldSteps`() executes, spring first checks whether `EntityManager` exists at `ThreadLocal` and reuse if already exists (in order to join existing persistence context).

So, when `saveListOfValidationSteps`() gets called from outside, spring will start new transaction and when `deleteOldSteps` is called from local it will join the existing transaction (due to `ThrealLocal` data).

**NOTE:** But if `deleteOldSteps` is not annotated with `@Transactional`, and if `deleteOldSteps` will not start a new transaction, because local calls do not get captured by spring aspects.